# Multiple TCPServer/Client C#

Tags: c#, tcp, tcpclient, tcpserver

I am trying to learn C# programming language. I have a very simple question here. I wanted to make TCPServer and TCPClient. but I couldn't quite do what I wanted to do. What I want is to have 4 clients on 1 server and they can talk to each other. I want the names of the people speaking to be determined individually. Please can anyone help with this? (Sorry for bad english)

/Server Code/

```
    namespace SimpleTcpSrvr
    {
        class Program
        {
            //private static object mTcpClient;
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
    
                Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                int asd;
                byte[] data = new byte[1024];
                
                IPEndPoint asd2 = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 1302);
                Socket newsocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                newsocket.Bind(asd2);
                newsocket.Listen(100);
                Console.WriteLine("waiting for connection...");
                Socket client = newsocket.Accept();
                IPEndPoint clientep = (IPEndPoint)client.RemoteEndPoint;
    
                
                var socket = (Socket)client;
                Console.WriteLine((string.Format("New connection: " + socket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString())));
    
                string welcome = "Chat Server";
                data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Welcome my chat server);
                
                client.Send(data, data.Length, SocketFlags.None);
                string input;
    
                while (true)
                {
                    data = new byte[1024];
                    asd = client.Receive(data);
                    if (asd == 0)
                        break;
    
                    
    
                    Console.WriteLine("TCPClient: " + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 0, asd));
                    input = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop - 1);
                    Console.WriteLine("You: " + input);
                    client.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));
                }
                Console.WriteLine("{0}'sinin bağlantısı kesildi.", clientep.Address);
                client.Close();
                newsocket.Close();
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
```

/Client Code/

```
    namespace TCPClient
    {
        public class TcpClient
        {
            
    
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
               
    
                Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.ASCII;
                byte[] data = new byte[1024];
                string input, stringData;
                IPEndPoint asd2 = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 1302);
                Socket newsocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    
                try
                {
                    newsocket.Connect(asd2);
                }
                catch (SocketException e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("cant connect server");
                    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                    return;
                }
    
                int asd = newsocket.Receive(data);
                stringData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 0, asd);
                Console.WriteLine(stringData);
    
                while (true)
                {
                    input = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop - 1);
                    Console.WriteLine("You: " + input);
                    newsocket.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));
                    data = new byte[1024];
                    asd = newsocket.Receive(data);
                    stringData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 0, asd);
                    byte[] utf8string = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringData);
                    
                    Console.WriteLine("TCPServer:" + stringData);
                }
    
                Console.WriteLine("connection lost from server...");
                newsocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                newsocket.Close();
                Console.WriteLine("disconnected!");
                Console.ReadLine();
    
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you are doing this as a learning exercise, I would recommend a using higher protocol than TCP. It would be fairly rare to use TCP directly in the real world. You will likely get something usable much faster if you use something like [NetMq](https://netmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), [gRPC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/basics?view=aspnetcore-5.0) or just a regular REST web-server.

Comment: Your question is mostly fine so far, however, you forgot to say what you need help with. Can you [edit] it so we have a clear idea of what's not working or what you can't achieve?

Comment: Outside the question, what the actual question is, for a beginner, I would recommend to tackling something _way_ simpler than a Chat-System. It _may sound_ easy enough, but it actually isn't. Especially if you want to do it from scratch and are not familiar with different transport layer protocols, how to implement and / or use higher protocols, multithreading, ...

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I want 4 client users to communicate over 1 server. but i don't know how to include it in this code i want your help on this

Comment: @JonasH I want to do this program using TCP. Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, it has to be said, there are a million-and-one edge cases when working with sockets - unless you are actually writing a new `transport-protocol` to run over TCP, you'd be much better off investing your time into learning an existing transport such as HTTP or gRPC.

**With that disclaimer out of the way:**

1. Use `TcpListener()` instead of `Socket()` in your server.
2. Use `TcpClient()` instead of `Socket()` in your client.
3. Your server needs to be able to simultaneously handle multiple clients, for this, use the Task-based Asyncronous Pattern (TAP).

So in your server, you need an instance of `TcpClient()` for every connection that your server `accepts()`.

Start with a place to store all of your Tasks, e.g.,

```
static List<Task> Tasks = new();
```

Next you need a `TcpListener` which accepts incomming connections and spawns a Task to manage the TcpClient associated with that connection e.g.,

```
static async Task RunServerAsync()
{
    TcpListener tcpListener = new(IPAddress.Loopback, 9999);
    tcpListener.Start();
    while (true)
    {
        var tcpClient = await tcpListener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
        Tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => RunClientAsync(tcpClient)));
    }
}
```

A simple `TcpClient` Task would look something like this

```
static async Task RunClientAsync(TcpClient tcpClient)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Connection from: [{tcpClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint}]");
    var reader = new StreamReader(tcpClient.GetStream());

    while (true)
    {
        var line = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
        Console.WriteLine($"{tcpClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint}: {line}");
    }
}
```

You can tie this together in a `Main()` like this:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    await Task.Run(() => RunServerAsync());
}
```

Now you have a very simple echo-line server that will accept connections from as many clients as you can throw at it.

To wrap it up, you could use the TAP to create clients, for your testing, maybe something like:

```
static async Task RunClientAsync(string message)
{
    var tcpClient = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 9999);
    StreamWriter sw = new(tcpClient.GetStream());
    tcpClient.NoDelay = true;
    while(true)
    { 
        await sw.WriteLineAsync(message);
        await sw.FlushAsync();
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
}
```

And of course you'd need to update your Main to support this, e.g.,

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    _ = Task.Run(() => RunServerAsync());

    await Task.Delay(1000); // give the server a sec to start

    _ = Task.Run(() => RunClientAsync("This is from client1"));
    _ = Task.Run(() => RunClientAsync("Client2 is here!!"));
    _ = Task.Run(() => RunClientAsync("And I am client3"));

    await Task.Delay(int.MaxValue);
}
```

Of course in a real application you'd never fire and forget your Tasks like that.

Full code for the sake of completeness:

```
class Program
{
    static List<Task> Tasks = new();
    static async Task RunClientAsync(TcpClient tcpClient)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Connection from: [{tcpClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint}]");
        var reader = new StreamReader(tcpClient.GetStream());

        while (true)
        {
            var line = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
            Console.WriteLine($"{tcpClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint}: {line}");
        }
    }
    static async Task RunServerAsync()
    {
        TcpListener tcpListener = new(IPAddress.Loopback, 9999);
        tcpListener.Start();
        while (true)
        {
            var tcpClient = await tcpListener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
            Tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => RunClientAsync(tcpClient)));
        }
    }
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        _ = Task.Run(() => RunServerAsync());

        await Task.Delay(1000); // give the server a sec to start

        _ = Task.Run(() => RunClientAsync("This is from client1"));
        _ = Task.Run(() => RunClientAsync("Client2 is here!!"));
        _ = Task.Run(() => RunClientAsync("And I am client3"));

        await Task.Delay(int.MaxValue);
    }

    static async Task RunClientAsync(string message)
    {
        var tcpClient = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 9999);
        StreamWriter sw = new(tcpClient.GetStream());
        tcpClient.NoDelay = true;
        while(true)
        { 
            await sw.WriteLineAsync(message);
            await sw.FlushAsync();
            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please also explain how to close the `TcpListner` safely in your above code. Very helpful code. Upvoted.